# How to change all control style as per my own theme in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, themes, controls

I have a project with over 50 forms and each forms having over 20 different controls. Now, I don't like the design of the project. I have already many great vb.net themes class modules files. So, I now want to use those theme inside all my forms. Now, when I compile a theme class, it creates new themed controls as usual, but I need something, if that I use on my each form, the whole form and all controls look will automatically changed to that style theme. I don't need to reuse or farther don't need to take any new controls with that style. I think I can clear my point. Is there any other kind of theme or ocx file available there in net, free or premium by which I am able to do it. Actually I really need great professional looking forms and controls. looking for your help.

Comment: You could loop over each form and over each control in side the form. Then apply styles based on your template. If you are asking for a library or tool suggestion, you are on the wrong site.

Comment: "You could loop over each form and over each control in side the form." please explain that